# Reasons for repeated uniqueidentifier?

Tags: sql-server, uniqueidentifier, sqldatatypes

I am consuming this table from an external source to my local datamart:

[image]

I did a GroupBy/count on EFGuid and I got:

[image]

So I assume the creator of the table (on this external source) committed a mistake by creating it as uniqueidentifier? Or could there be a reason to pick such data type?

Two questions:

- I will consume this data, so of course I do not need a `uniqueidentifier` data type, is it ok to pick `nvarchar(320)` just to store this?
- does this external source has a performance penalty for picking `uniqueIdentifier` instead of `nvarchar`?

Comment: `consume`? what do you mean by that? `uniqueidentifer`, as the name suggest is unique. in your case, maybe that EFGuid is referencing to something. If you don't need the `EFGuid` then don't include it in your table.

Comment: Why would it be a mistake for them to use uniqueidentifier?

Comment: What is efguid used for?

Comment: @geoman By consume I mean, (create an ETL: external source -> local datamart). UniqueIdentifier may not be unique (as I have proven before). Peter, unless you are populating it with NEWID() picking up uniqueidentifier as datatype makes no sense (correct me if wrong).  not sure what is it used for. I guess the answer to my question is   CHAR(36).

Answer (score 2):

Grouping or filtering by `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` or `NVARCHAR(320)` is slower versus `INT` (let's say). The `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` is `CHAR(36)`:

```
SELECT LEN(NEWID())
```

So, you do not need `NVARCHAR(320)`, too. It depends, on what you are going to do with the data, after all, but you can create a separated table with the following columns:

```
[InteralEFID] INT IDENTITY(100, 1)
[EFGuid] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
```

So, when you perform the migration you can use the new `INT` column instead. This will for sure reduce the size of the table and can increase performance for various operations. You can keep the new table (EFID <-> EFGuid mapping) for future imports, or if you need to get the `EF GUID` for some `EF ID` for some reason.